# Create multiple form instances

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to create multiple form instances. For example, i have a form1 and form2
and there is a ListView in form1.

When ever clicked the item in ListView , it will create a new instance of form2.

```
Form2 listview1.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text = new Form2();
listview1.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text.Show();
```

But C# don't allow me to do that, any idea? (yes.. i got errors :D )

Ok, the idea is .. let say i want to have 3 instances of form2,

`Form2 f21 = new Form2();`

`Form2 f22 = new Form2();`

`Form2 f23 = new Form2();`

and now I'll have 3 form2, but what if i don't know how many form[s] i might create ? (create form base of the items in listview dynamically)

Actually this maybe not the right way to do it ... Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: i don't even know where to start with this one... what are you trying to do?

Comment: `.Text` is not a form, it's a string.

Comment: I think you're problem is deeper then your lines of code, it's your understanding of OO, property types and instances.  You can copy paste suggestions from the people below, but it's useless if you don't understand it.  You might want to run a few tutorials first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listview1.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text` is a `string` property, *you can not assign* `System.Windows.Forms.Form` to `string`.

not very clear what you're going to achieve here, but, **may be** something like this

```
new Form2().Show();
```

on click of the item would be enough for you.

If it's not what you're asking for, please clarify.

**EDIT**

To manage arbitrary quantity of forms, you can do something like:

```
//somewhere in the code a global collection
var formsCollection = new List<Form>();
```

and on click on item:

```
formsCollection.Add(new Form2());
formsCollection[formsCollection.Count-1].Show();
```

The other thing to mantion it that **may be** you will need to find some specific form in the collection (for some reason). You can assign some special property to Form2, some unique identifier, in order to be able to find it after, on request.

Comment: i edited my question. :D , i know we cant assign System.Windows.Forms.Form to string but how if i want the form to be dynamic ?

Comment: Hi, this should be what i looking for. Maybe i google with the wrong "key words" :D anyway, appreciate and thank for the help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that by not being allowed to do so means that you are getting some kind of error. Is it a syntax error? That would be my guess.

Also, why are you creating a new form for every new click? I would recommend re-use of existing object or proper destruction/dereferencing of the old one.

I believe that there is a problem with the line

```
Form2 listview1.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text = new Form2();
```

You cannot assign new forms to a text property and furthermore, in this kind of statement you are supposed to provide a name for the variable, not a reference somewhere else.
Did you mean something like:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(listview1.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text);
f2.Show();
```

Comment: Thank for answering, i did search with google and found some answer similar with yours. but i need to post different data to each form for monitoring purpose.